# How to remove column adjuster in Lightning Data Table?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, slds

I have a Lightning Data Table component in my Lightning web component that displays data in several columns. By default, the data table displays a column adjuster in the top right corner of each column, which allows the user to resize the columns. However, I want to remove this feature so that the columns have a fixed width. Please refer below image for more details.

Is there a way to remove the column adjuster for all columns in a Lightning Data Table component?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "resize-column-disabled" property on lightning-datatable, (as mentioned in the documentation)[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation]

> To prevent users from resizing columns, specify resize-column-disabled in your markup. The table can still adjust its column widths when you resize the browser window or the width of the parent container changes. The resize-column-disabled attribute allows the table to resize columns when column-widths-mode is set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

In your `columns` attribute, set the property for `fixedWidth` to the desired value in pixels. These columns will not be resizable, and the right-hand grip will disappear (do this for all columns to fix all columns to some width).